# Overline too long in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why it's longer than text on the left side. Same for the rest of the menu items.

This is what my overline looks like.

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/4vugfaks/)

Here's the HTML of the list:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href ="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About stuff</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the corresponding CSS:

```
ul.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-color: 000000;
    word-spacing: 0.3em;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
    line-height: 120%;
    text-decoration: overline;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-shadow: 0.04em 0.04em #000000;
}
```

Comment: Also - `text-color: 000000;` should be `color: #000000;`. You might want to [apply it to `a:link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `text-decoration: overline;` from `ul.menu` and put it in `li`.

See my snippet:

```css
ul.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-color: 000000;
    word-spacing: 0.3em;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
    line-height: 120%;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-shadow: 0.04em 0.04em #000000;
}

li {
    text-decoration: overline;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href ="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About stuff</a></li>
</ul>
```